# Solr collection is not updating the value of one field on same rowid while updating thogh hbase batch batch indexer

Tags: hadoop, solr

I am not able to update the value of one field in solr collection When I am updating the data throgh hbase .

hbase data

3235900531-0,3235900531,3
3235900028-0,3235900028,3
3235900029-0,3235900028,6

For the first time data is properly inserted when I am running the batch indexer again with the updated value and same row id data is not getting updated in solr collection and duplicate data also not there

3235900531-0,3235900531,5
3235900028-0,3235900028,8
3235900029-0,3235900028,9

Can anyone help me on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It may be happening due to the duplicate keys. solr takes a unique id for indexing if unique id will contain duplicate elements the records will be overridden.

Comment: Solr key is unique and I am trying to update the value of one element on the same key when the value update in hbase I run the hbase batch indexer and it run successfully but on the same key the value is not updated in solr.

Comment: try to use a different key or use a delta import approach.